# php writing text file creation format

Tags: php

I need to store some data in a text file.  The data is in my mysql as latin1 to use as few bytes as possible.  How can I make a text file for php to write to in latin1 format please?

Comment: Using UTF-8 won't take up any more space unless it actually needs to. Is the usage of latin1 set in stone? (Bit retrograde, hence the question.)

Comment: Not set in stone as such, just storing a LOT of text (a-z and 0-9) no fancy stuff, so thought their might be a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst slightly off-topic, to be honest I'd be tempted to keep everything (web page, database connection, table/collation, output files, etc. in UTF-8), purely in the (*quite possibly epically unlikely*) eventuality that non latin1 characters are required at any point in the future.

Virtually all text editors, etc. support UTF-8 as-is and it'll be easier to convert from UTF-8 to another format (and conversely from another format to UTF-8) if so required. Additionally, database (and disk space) is ridiculously cheap, so using up a few bytes here and there in comparison to committing to a limited character set would seem a bit of an excessive trade-off.

Incidentally, there's a fairly canonical blog post related to such things by [Joel Spolsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) called: "[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)". It's well worth a read irrespective of which way you decide to go.